# Slower inference time while using multiple parallel processes on the same GPU in tensorflow C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, parallel-processing, nvidia

I am trying to run multiple parallel inferences on the same GPU. In order to do that, I loaded the graph multiple times in different processes because I am in a real-time system and I can’t batch the input.
The mean inference time for only one worker is around 0.02 seconds while for multiple workers is more than 0.03, growing proportionally with the number of processes. I set the per process GPU memory fraction to 0.02 and allow growth to false, anything above this limit would not improve the inference speed.

Theoretically, if the GPU would be able of parallelization, the process should be as many times faster as the number of workers, or at least close. Unfortunately, the inference time is slower while I am increasing the number of workers. I’m a getting an overall speed boost from splitting the dataset of up to 1.5-2x times faster, but the mean inference time is still slower.

There isn’t any hardware limitation or bottleneck from either GPU or CPU as can be seen in the following image https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCy3D.jpg

The benchmark can be seen on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t67rO.jpg

Now, I am thinking that maybe CUDA does not allow parallelization or is something wrong in my code. Anyone has any idea about what might be the problem?

Os Platform: Linux 16.04
Tensorflow C++ installed from source
Tensorflow version 1.12
CUDA/cudnn version 9.2/7.1
GPU Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

Comment: Different processes cannot simultaneously share the GPU. There is always context switching involved

Comment: But, can different threads share the GPU?

Comment: Different threads can "share" the same GPU context, which eliminates the context switch performance hit. But to "share" the GPU, all the requirements for kernel concurrency must be satisfied, which includes sufficient GPU resources, correct use of streams, no blocking calls or dependencies, etc